# Dynamic Reloading with Glassfish and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I am just starting out with Java EE development and as an exercise I am trying to set up a basic project development cycle using Eclipse and Glassfish.

I am looking at something like the following setup (I think) - Develop a project in Eclipse (say Project1) and deploy it on local glassfish server via exploded directory deployment. Synchronize project files between project being developed in Eclipse and those in the exploded directory via FileSync plugin so the deployed application can be dynamically reloaded.

1) Where in the glassfish directory hierarchy should the exploded directory for Project1 be located? What is the proper way to set it up (I was thinking use asadmin deploy Eclipse/workspace/Project1, I'm not sure if that is correct)

2) Are there any additional things (configurations/etc) I should be aware of and take into account.

I've been unable to find any conclusive answers from looking around (or haven't recognized them, anyway). Any help or pointers in the right direction from anyone who has done this before would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set things up manually. There is a GF plugin for Eclipse, which provides a nice integration including the "redeploy on save". See http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed that. Question - where does the glassfish plugin map exploded directory to? Also, does redeploy on save restart the application server or just reload the changed files. For reference, I was looking at setting up a system similar to the on here, though it's with glassfish 2.1 - http://naheece.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/dynamic-reloading-hot-deployment-on-glassfish-2-1/

Comment: The plugin is integrated with Eclipse, so if you have auto-republish set than each resource save will republish your application; it will not restart your AS.

Comment: Thanks. Another quick question - from what I understand the project was published to glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\__internal\, where I have the Project1 directory. However, it's an empty directory. Does this mean the project is being deployed from Eclipse's workspace directory rather than locally (ie if I was working with a remote glassfish server instead would the project be stored just on my machine under Eclipse)?